# what's the use of java virtual method invokation?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Say I have the following code

```
public class A {
  public void callme() {
    System.out.println("Calling of class A function ");
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public void callme() {
    System.out.println(" Calling of class B fuction ");
  }

  public void Hello() {
    System.out.println("hello guys");
  }
}
```

and a main() that does the following

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    A a = new B();
    B b = new B();

    b = (B)a;
    a.callme();
    b.callme();
    a.Hello(); // show error : Hello is undefined for method A
  }
}
```

The book says "you get the behavior associated with the object to which the variable refers at runtime". Ok, I get behavior of B class when a method callme is called, but when I access the method Hello, it shows an error that Hello is undefined for method A.  why is that?

Comment: Because the variable `a` is of type `A` and class `A` does not have a `Hello` method.

Comment: Behavior != Interface

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism doesn't work this way. Since A is parent of B, B can inherit methods of A (like son can inherit properties of father), but its not vice versa because A doesn't know which classes are inheriting it (A does not know who are its children.)

For Example, suppose there is one more class C:

```
public class C extends A {
public void callme(){

System.out.println(" Calling of class C fuction ");
}

public void Hello(){

System.out.println("hello guys, I am C");
}
}
```

Now, if you use

```
a.Hello();
```

how will a know which child class it should call since it does not methods of its child. only its own abstract method, which it knows child will implement for sure.

Comment: So then what's the benefit of A a = new B();// virtual method invokation..I could have simply used object of B class to call the functions. Why do we use virual method invokation?

Answer (score 0):

`a` is of type `A`, even if it is referring to an instance of `B`.

`A` doesn't have the `Hello` method (even an `abstract` declaration). So your compiler emits the error. Adjusting your code slightly to

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract void Hello();
    /*the rest as before*/
```

would be a fix. `A` is then assuming the characteristics of an *interface*.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class B extends A {
public void callme(){

System.out.println(" Calling of class B fuction ");
}

public void Hello(){ // hello method is only the part of class B not A.

System.out.println("hello guys");
}
}
```

In above class `hello()` method is a part of B only. it not override by the method of A.

now in your main method call

```
public static void main(String [] args){
A a= new B();  // object of b referred by (a) Reference Variable of A
B b= new B();  // object of b referred by (b) Reference Variable of B

b= (B)a;
a.callme();  //override takes place and method of B's Callme() called
b.callme();  //again override takes place here and method of B's Callme() called
a.Hello();// buttttttt
b.Hello(); // this will compile and executes fine.
}
}
```

Here you used the reference variable of class `A` which don't have any method name `Hello()`. So, Method Resolution will not take place(won't be able to find any method like `Hello()`).

but if you try to call `b.Hello()` using the reference variable of `B` then it will work fine to you.

Now suppose there is another class C which is a sub class of A and contains a Method Name `Hello()`.

```
public class C extends A {

    public void Hello(){ // hello method is only the part of class B not A.

    System.out.println("hello guys");
    }
    }
```

In main a Statement like this

```
A a = new C();
```

and if you try to call `a.Hello()` then which `Hello()` method will call. Compiler will get confused.

So, This concept work only when you try to override the method of super class in sub Class.

Answer (score 0):

Is the parent class aware of classes derived from it ?

**Casting does not change the actual object type. Only the reference type gets changed.**

I highly recommend you my upcasting and downcasting writing from [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38265382/4990642)